# NextJS Tailwind Styling Gone Wrong

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

When i'm using the component seperated, the results was look weird like this
Seperated Component Code:

```
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Staycation | Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="description" content="We provide what you need to enjoy your holiday with family. House, Villa, Resort booking administration." />
        <meta name="og:title" content="Staycation | Home" />
        <meta name="og:description" content="We provide what you need to enjoy your holiday with family. House, Villa, Resort booking administration." />
      </Head>
      <div className="min-h-screen">
        <NavbarComponent />
        <HeroSection />
        <MostPickedSection />
        <CategoriesSection />
        <TestimonialSection />
        <FooterComponent />
      </div>
    </>
```

[image: Weird Result]

And if i'm put the component directly without seperated, the results was good

```
      <Head>
        <title>Staycation | Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="description" content="We provide what you need to enjoy your holiday with family. House, Villa, Resort booking administration." />
        <meta name="og:title" content="Staycation | Home" />
        <meta name="og:description" content="We provide what you need to enjoy your holiday with family. House, Villa, Resort booking administration." />
      </Head>
      <div className="min-h-screen">
        <NavbarComponent />
        <div className="flex flex-col-reverse md:flex-row container-item mt-4 md:mt-16">
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-between flex-1">
            <div className="flex md:block flex-col items-center">
              <h1 className="mt-5 md:mt-0 font-bold text-center md:text-left text-2xl md:text-5xl text-primaryColor" style={{ lineHeight: '170%' }}>
                FORGOT BUSY WORK,
                <br />
                START NEXT VACATION
              </h1>
              <p className="w-4/5 md:w-2/5 mx-auto md:mx-0 mt-2 font-light text-center md:text-left text-xs md:text-base text-greyColor" style={{ lineHeight: '170%' }}>
                We provide what you need to enjoy your holiday with family. Time to make another memorable moments.
              </p>
              <button type="button" className="w-4/5 md:w-1/3 py-4 md:py-4 mt-3 md:mt-8 md:font-medium text-xs md:text-base rounded-md shadow-2xl transition-all duration-75 hover:opacity-80 text-whiteColor bg-secondaryColor">
                Show Me Now
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="hidden md:flex justify-between items-center w-2/3">
              <HeroItem icon="/icons/Travellers.svg" title="10.203" description="Travellers" />
              <HeroItem icon="/icons/Treasures.svg" title="781" description="Treasures" />
              <HeroItem icon="/icons/Cities.svg" title="1.492" description="Cities" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end flex-1">
            <img src="../images/Hero.png" alt="Hero" className="w-full md:w-4/5 mt-2 md:mt-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <MostPickedSection />
        <CategoriesSection />
        <TestimonialSection />
        <FooterComponent />
      </div>
```

[image: Good Result]
And if i'm change the code again from the non-seperated to seperated component again(after getting good result), it will back to good result
I hope you guys know what i mean, i'm so confuse about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and this fixed my issue ( I was using react tho )

1. Change the component extension from .jsx to .js

   or
2. Include .jsx in your content in tailwind.config.js

> ```
> /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
> module.exports = {
>   content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
>   theme: {
>     extend: {},
>   },
>   plugins: [],
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple of reasons why:

- you may have to restart the project to tailwind to compile.
- you may have to check if your `tailwind directives` are in the `styles/globals.css`.
- check your `tailwind.config.js` file to see if the HeroSection component is within the specified paths in the contents array.
- 